# Identity not working and cannot access Identity data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I'm not sure what I did, but I seem to have messed up my ASP.NET Core Identity. It was working. I was able to create an account and login. But now I can't log in, and the Forgot Password function won't send me an email. Some tests indicated `UserManager.FindByNameAsync()` was returning `null` when there was data matching the request.

I'm getting some strange results as I try to debug this. The following line returns all the `Goal`s in my database.

```
var goals = DbContext.Goals.AsEnumerable();
```

However, the following line returns an empty results set. (I have one row in the *AspNetUsers* table.)

```
var users = DbContext.Users.AsEnumerable();
```

I have not scaffolded Identity in this project. Here are a couple of related classes.

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Space to add custom fields
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Goal> Goals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

So basically anything that tries to access the Identity classes fails. What could possibly prevent me from reading the Users table? The only thing I can think of is that I messed something up with my `ApplicationUser` class. Can anyone recommend what else I might try to isolate this? I'm blocked.

Comment: Have you been able to harvest any error messages?

Comment: @DaniDev: I don't get any errors. It just returns an empty resultset as though the table has no rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides, if you would ike to use custom user data, you also need to use the `ApplicationUser` type as a generic argument for the context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-user-data

Comment: This was my issue. Thanks.